# Dealing with type erasure inside a Scala List

Tags: scala, type-erasure

I have some classes like

```
sealed trait Animal
case class Bird(name:String, birdField: BirdType) extends Animal
case class Cat(name:String, catField: CatType) extends Animal
```

And then a class like

```
case class AnimalWrapper(id:Int, animal:Animal)
```

and a

```
List[AnimalWrapper]
```

What would be the best approach to extract an `Cat` for example, from the `AnimalWrapper`, and the do a mapping to have access to its `catField`?

Something like

```
animalWrapper.getThisAnimal[Cat](byName).map(_.catField)
```

I cat use a `ClassTag` to get any animal from the list, like `getThisAnimal[T <:Animal <:ClassTag]: Option[T]`, but I can't do the mapping without an ugly casting before, which is really unacceptable.
 I haven't found anything useful or at least a decent workaround to this, so any ideas? 
Thank you

Comment: Because you have two different types in your collection you need to do pattern matching over the Animal type. If you want to avoid the ClassCastException

Comment: What is the result you want? A **List** with all **Cats** in the original **List**? The first **Cat** of the **List**? Ensure all elements are **Cats**? Do a `map` which chose which operation to do based on if each element is a **Cat** or a **Bird**?

Comment: An `Option[AnimalWrapper]`, upon which I can do `birdField` or `catField` without any cast, like `getThisAnimal[Cat].map(_.animal.catField)`

Comment: The problem is that `AnimalWrapper` looses all type information, so even if you are sure what you will have inside the wrapper is an **Bird** the compiler will not accept it unless you do a dirty cast. - Maybe we could modify the wrapper class? Or maybe you do not need to return the wrapper class at all, just a tuple of the animal and the id? - Also, you mention an **Option** so I guess you want the first match _(if any)_ inside the **List**?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need casting, this is what pattern-matching is for:

```scala
case class AnimalWrapper(id:Int, animal:Animal) {

  def getThisAnimal[T <: Animal](implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): Option[T] = {
    animal match {
       case t: T => Some(t)
       case _    => None
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: It seems to duplicate `ct.unapply`: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/reflect/ClassTag.html#unapply(x:Any):Option[T]

Comment: The problem is not in getting the class, but accessing its fields. Because what you get back from `List[Animalwrapper]` - and I want it this way- is an `AnimalWrapper`, which does not know about the `Animal` type

Comment: @user2963757 I don't understand what you expect then, perhaps you can give more details or enrich the code sample you provided in your original question. Give us the inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: An Option[AnimalWrapper], upon which I can do birdField or catField without any cast, like getThisAnimal[Cat].map(_.animal.catField)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. You have to make `AnimalWrapper` a generic, like `AnimalWrapper[T <: Animal]`. And then 
 `def getThisAnimal[T <:Animal:ClassTag]:Option[AnimalWrapper[T]] =` 
`animalWrapper.collectFirst {`
 `case AnimalWrapper(id, animal: T) => AnimalWrapper[T](id, animal)`
`}`. 
 Now you can map over without any cast. Hope will help someone else.

Comment: It probably would be better to use a **typeclass** rather than relying on class checks.